ColdFusion Oracle 12c Two Year date defaulting to 1900s instead of 2000s
I have a form with a number of date fields in it.
input tag - cfinput type="text" name="orientation_date" value="#dateFormat(getData.orientation_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')#" required="no" message="Please enter an Orientation date in mm/dd/yyyy format" validate="date" maxlength="10" size="10"
data insert format in the insert query - createODBCdate(form.orientation_date)
oracle datatype - Date
When I enter a two digit year up to 29, it enters the data as 2029. When I enter anything 30 or above, it enters the data as 1930.
Is there a fix for this besides forcing the end user to use four digit dates? We have a requirement for people to complete a degree by up to 10 years after their start date, so we have a lot of dates that are showing as the 1930s.
Basically I want the default for two digit years to be 19 only if the number is 50 or higher, not 30 or higher. Is that a setting somewhere in Oracle? I've been looking, but I'm not finding it.

You can use CF to apply that logic before sending the data to Oracle.

Proper solution would be to enter 2029 instead of just 29. Did you never hear about the Y2K-Bug?

Use javascript form-validation to modify the two digits to four using whatever logic you wish. It's best to avoid using 2-digit years when talking to the database.

I don't think it's a good idea to pass the input string to createODBCTimeStamp. You should check if the input is a valid date. You may set the right century there, too
